# Como realizar concatenação SQL

Tags: sql-server, tsql, ssms

Preciso concatenar ano e mês. Como eu poderia fazer isso?

```
    select cast(year(orderdate) as int) + ' ' + cast(month(OrderDate)as int) as Year_Month
    From sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas solucionou teu problema?

Answer (score 3):

Usa a função [CONCAT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql).

```
SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(OrderDate), '-', MONTH(OrderDate)) AS Year_Month
FROM sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

Nesse caso, o segundo parâmetro do *concat* é o separador (*'-'*) que você define o que vai ser.

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar o CONCAT do sql

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql

```
select Concat(cast(year(orderdate) as int),  '_'  ,cast(month(OrderDate)as int)) as Year_Month From sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

Comment: Não é necessário fazer um `Cast` em `Ano` e `Mês`, pois os valores que são passados como argumentos dentro da função `Concat` são diretamente convertidos para `texto`

Answer (score 1):

Deram a opção do `CONCAT`, mas ele foi implatado no `SQL SERVER 2012`, é bem provável que esteja utilizando o `2008` e seja incompatível.

Para fazer a concatenação, é necessário que seja uma `string`. Da forma como está fazendo ocorrerá erro, então concatene da seguinte maneira utilizando `YEAR()` e `MONTH` com `CAST()`:

```
SELECT CAST(YEAR(orderdate) AS NVARCHAR(4)) + ' ' + CAST(MONTH(orderdate) AS NVARCHAR(2)) AS year_month
```

Ou utilizando `DATEPART`:

```
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(yyyy, orderdate) AS NVARCHAR(4)) + ' ' + CAST(DATEPART(mm, orderdate) AS NVARCHAR(2)) AS year_month
```

Answer (score 1):

## [CONCAT (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/concat-transact-sql)

> Retorna uma string que é o resultado de concatenar dois ou mais
> valores de seqüência de caracteres. Está disponivel a parti do SQL- Server 2012.

**Query:**

```
select CONCAT('O ano em que estamos é ', YEAR(GETDATE()),' e o mês é ', 
MONTH(GETDATE())) as Data
```

*Nota: Todos os argumentos são implicitamente convertidos em tipos de string e, em seguida, concatenados. Então não é necessário usar o T-SQL `CAST` conforme perguntando.*

## [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1e1f4fbf1/3041/0)

Answer (score 0):

Joana, no código sql que você postou fique atenta para os meses cujo valor numérico é menor do que 10. Por exemplo, 12/11/2008 ficará como "2008 11" mas 12/1/2008 ficará como "2008 1", quando me parece que o esperado é "2008 01".

Uma forma simples e rápida de obter o que desejada é utilizar a função CONVERT(), convertendo de *date* para *string*. Algo assim:

```
-- código #1
SELECT convert (char(7), orderdate, 23) as Year_Month
  from sales.SalesOrderHeader;
```

Se não desejar o hífen entre ano e mês, eis uma variação:

```
-- código #2
SELECT replace (convert (char(7), orderdate, 23), '-', ' ') as Year_Month
  from sales.SalesOrderHeader;
```

Observe que com essa solução não é necessário o uso de operador ou função de concatenação e nem de se preocupar com meses cujo valor seja menor do que 10. Mas se estiver interessada em realizar concatenação, sugiro a leitura do artigo [Concatenação de cadeias de caracteres](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2020/03/12/concatenacao-string/).

Answer (score -2):

Joana, fiz isso e deu certo. Talvez também funcione pra você:

```
select 
    concat(cast(year(orderdate) as varchar),'-', cast(MONTH(OrderDate) as varchar)) as Year_Month
From sales.SalesOrderHeader
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).